# Поменять значение disabled в input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть две радиокнопки:

```
<input type="radio" name="payment" value="nal" checked=""> Наличными<br>
<input type="radio" name="payment" value="beznal"> Безналичными<br>
```

Есть input:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="bin" required disabled="">
```

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на `radio` «безналичными» атрибут инпута `disabled` отключался, и наоборот, чтобы включался при нажатии на `radio` «наличными»?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### jQuery 1.6+

`disabled` — это не просто атрибут в HTML-коде, это специальное свойство у объекта `HTMLInputElement`, значение которого имеет тип Boolean, поэтому в jQuery его правильнее всего менять с помощью метода [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop):

```
$("input").prop('disabled', true);
$("input").prop('disabled', false);
```

### jQuery 1.5 и более старые

В старых версиях `.prop()` отсутствует, так что придётся откатываться до [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) (это некрасиво, но тем не менее тоже работает благодаря [специальному костылю](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/ac9e3016645078e1e42120822cfb2076151c8cbe/src/attributes/attr.js#L46)).

Включить `disabled`:

```
$("input").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Выключить `disabled`:

```
$("input").removeAttr('disabled');
```

*(использовать `removeProp` для ранее упомянутого специального свойства `disabled` нельзя!)*

О том, что это некрасиво, говорит [сама документация jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

> [As of jQuery 1.6, ], To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the `checked`, `selected`, or `disabled` state of form elements, use the `.prop()` method.

### В любой версии jQuery или совсем без него

Если любыми путями достать настоящий DOM-объект (`HTMLInputElement`), то можно просто взять и поменять у него свойство `disabled` без всяких jQuery (правда, это будет применимо только к одному элементу за раз, в то время как jQuery умеет переключать `disabled` сразу пачке элементов, но сейчас не об этом).

Например, если повесить на требуемый элемент обработчик какого-нибудь события (без `bind`), то значением `this` там будет DOM-элемент, и тогда:

```
this.disabled = true;
```

Или можно достать DOM-элемент из jQuery-объекта:

```
$('input')[0].disabled = true;
```

---

Выше был вольный перевод [ответа с английского Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1414366) с дополнениями. Если применить данные знания к вашей задаче, то получится как-то так:

```js
$('input[name="payment"]').on('click', function(){
  $('input[name="bin"]').prop('disabled', $(this).val() != 'beznal');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="payment" value="nal" checked=""> Наличными<br>
<input type="radio" name="payment" value="beznal"> Безналичными<br>

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="bin" required disabled="">
```

Comment: Спасибо, интересно! ) плюсую

Comment: Я тоже, но все же, пред идущие ответы назвать  неверными нельзя....

Comment: @Air ну лично я их не минусовал и называл не неверными, а «не такими уж и правильными» (всё-таки те ответы тоже работают), а за минусующих ничего сказать не могу)

Comment: Интересно тогда зачем тут написано так `disabled="disabled"`? http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/disabled

Comment: @RazGalstyan XHTML умер, так что уже незачем :)

Comment: @andreymal, не смею сомневаться....

Answer (score 4):

Вот к примеру так. С помощью `jquery`

```js
$('input[type=radio]').on('click',function(){
  if( $(this).val() == 'beznal' ){
    $('input[type=text]').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
  else{
    $('input[type=text]').attr('disabled','disabled');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="payment" value="nal" checked=""> Наличными<br>
<input type="radio" name="payment" value="beznal"> Безналичными<br>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="bin" required disabled="">
```

Comment: Интересно кто минусует правильный ответ????

Comment: @Air вообще то мне то же

Comment: Не парся, от дураков гарантии нет...)))  Это жизнь...

Comment: Оба ответа не такие уж и правильные ;) (но я не минусовал)

Comment: @andreymal, поясните, чем именно неправильные?

Comment: @andreymal ну да дали бы еще хороший ответ, и мы то же кое чему научились бы у вас.

Comment: @RazGalstyan я сейчас его написанием и занимаюсь

Comment: @andreymal Хорошо жду ответа

Comment: @andreymal, тоже жду, затаив дыхание :) Интересно, что же там такого, что мы с Raz Galstyan не учли...

Comment: @humster_spb о том, что вы не учли, написано прямо в документации jQuery, я её в своём ответе процитирую :)

Comment: Интригующая беседа, Господа)))))....  Меня тоже мое любопытство раздерает))))

Answer (score 2):

Можно так (c очисткой инпута, если вдруг снова выбран вариант "наличными")

```js
$('[type="radio"]').click(function(){
   if($(this).val() == 'beznal') {
      $('.form-control').attr('disabled', false);
   }
   else {
      $('.form-control').attr('disabled', true);
      $('.form-control').val('');
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="payment" value="nal" checked=""> Наличными<br>
<input type="radio" name="payment" value="beznal"> Безналичными<br>

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="bin" required disabled="">
```

Comment: Всё-таки значения атрибутов - это, как правило, строка. Даже метод `attr` в jQuery в качестве значения атрибута принимает `String`, `Number` и `Null`. То есть я за `prop('disabled', true)` и сильно не против `attr('disabled','disabled')`, но `attr('disabled', true)` - это что-то совсем неправильное. Кому-то в этом случае (вероятно, браузеру)  приходится самому `true` в `disabled` превращать.

Comment: @Regent в jQuery на такой случай [встроен костыль](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/ac9e3016645078e1e42120822cfb2076151c8cbe/src/attributes/attr.js#L46), преобразующий значение [некоторых атрибутов](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2d4f53416e5f74fa98e0c1d66b6f3c285a12f0ce/external/sizzle/dist/sizzle.js#L119) (в т.ч. `disabled`) в true/false (при наличии `prop()` предположу, что это ради обратной совместимости), а если скормить `true` браузеру в обход jQuery, то он честно сделает `disabled="true"` :)